# Mapping different type using automapper

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I am trying to map two different objects.
Suggestion without using ResolveUsing?
How to properly map string to object?

```
            cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
                    .ForPath(dest => dest.Users.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SourceName ))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Users.Users, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Users ))
```

model:

```
            public class Source
            {
                public string SourceName { get; set; }
                public List<User> Users { get; set; }
            }

            public class Destination
            {
                public List<User> Users { get; set; }
            }

            public class User
            {
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public List<User> Users { get; set; }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
dest => dest.Users.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SourceName)
```

Is not making much sense to me, even if it could work, it just means that all the `Users` would have the same `SourceName`, to map the names of the users from one list property to the other you just need to specify the property itself, `AutoMapper` will take care of the rest:

Something like this:

[Online sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ChSsjk)

```
using AutoMapper;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
```

```
public class Program
{
    public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Source
    {
        public List<User> Users { get; set; }
    }

    public class Destination
    {
        public List<User> Users { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
```

```
    // Config
    var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Users, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Users));
    });     
    var mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();
```

```
        // Test data
        var usersSource = new Source()
        {
            Users = new List<User>()
            {
                new User(){Name = "John"}, 
                new User(){Name = "Charles"}
            }
        };
        // Mapping
        var usersDestination = mapper.Map<Destination>(usersSource);
        
        // Verification
        Console.WriteLine(usersDestination.Users[0].Name + "\n" 
                          + usersDestination.Users[1].Name);
```

```
    }
}
```

Result:

> John 
> Charles

This is because `AutoMapper` is able to deal with known types, if you had a user defined type property, you would just create a new configuration for said user defined type like you did with `Source` and `Destination`. Needless to say that this could all be done *by hand* with direct assignment without the overhead, but that's a different conversation.